# infinite loop after removing node from user defined linked list (java)

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, infinite-loop, user-defined

```
public void dropCourse(String c)
{
    if(isEmpty())
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Empty Schedule");
    Node current = firstNode;
    Node follow = firstNode;
    follow = follow.getNext();
    current = current.getNext();
    while(!current.getClasses().equals(c) && current != null)
    {
        follow = current.getNext();
        current.setNext(follow.getNext());
        follow = null;
    }
    if(current.getClasses().equals(c))
    {
        follow.setNext(current);
        System.out.println("Class removed");
    }
}
```

I have this code in a method called `dropClass` it is supposed to remove the node from the

linked list and it works but when I try to print it in `toString` I get stuck in an infinite

loop, I found the line of code is `follow.setNext(current);` that seems to be the cause of the

infinite loop but I dont know what to do to fix, if I take it out it doesn't remove the

node buts prints correctly, here is where the infinite loop is happening

```
//Reads schedule
public String toString()
{
    if(isEmpty())
        return " ";
    else
    {
        String s = " ";
        Node current = firstNode;
        System.out.print("ID:");
        System.out.print(current.getId());
        current = current.getNext();
        while(current != null)
        {

            s = s + "Class:"
                  + current.getClasses()
                  + " Section:"
                  + current.getSection()
                  + " Credits:"
                  + current.getCredit()
                  + " ";
            current = current.getNext();

        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

the loop starts after `while(current != null)`, it works perfectly if I don't remove a node can some one explain what I did wrong when removing the node?

Edit:the setNext methods body

```
public void setNext(Node next)
{
    this.next = next;
}
```

also the loop i'm using to print out the linked lists

```
            for(int j = 0;j<list.length;j++)
            {
                one = list[j];
                System.out.println(one);
            }
```

I should also mention all the linked lists are in an array call list

Comment: Show the setNext method's body.

Comment: alright I updated my post

Comment: Why store the list elements in an array? Why aren't you using a `getNext()` method to iterate over the list?

Comment: Each element of the array is a sperate linked list, list[1] for example contains a linked list with a node that contains the students id and another node that has information about the course they are taking, while list[2] would have a different id and different course info

Comment: Why not define a class that contains the fields you are interested in storing and keep your list elements to single objects rather than use lists of lists to do that?